# Disable hiding of content of style parameter in HTML tag in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

**PhpStorm** hides content of style parameter in HTML tag, for example:

```
<div style="background: steelblue; float:left; ">
```

becames:

```
<div style="...">
```

Is it possible to **disable this feature**? I do not even know how is it called, so I have no idea what to search for.

Comment: You can always search for "Code Folding" in the settings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look in the Settings dialog, Editor, Code Folding and disable.

Comment: It was "HTML 'style' attribute" in Code Folding. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The path to this setting seem to be changed. On my Mac this was my path to change this:

Preferences > Editor > General > Code Folding > XML > Uncheck "HTML 'style'
attribute"